# compile FFMpeg for Android (Ubuntu14) - cannot locate symbol

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile FFMpeg for Android and I have troubles running the APK on Android 4 (on Android 5 I don't get this shitty unsatisfied link error):

```
05-09 15:16:18.880  22160-22304/com.gpac.Osmo4 I/LibrariesLoader﹕ Loading library avcodec...
05-09 15:16:18.910  22160-22304/com.gpac.Osmo4 E/dalvikvm﹕ dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.gpac.Osmo4-1/libavcodec.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "log2f" referenced by "libavcodec.so"...
05-09 15:16:18.920  22160-22304/com.gpac.Osmo4 E/LibrariesLoader﹕ Failed to load library : avcodec due to link error Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "log2f" referenced by "libavcodec.so"...
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "log2f" referenced by "libavcodec.so"...
```

I'm using NDK 10d, toolchain 4.9 but I was trying with NDK 8 and 9 also and I was getting the same result.
The only difference when I compile with older NDK versions is that I get a warning message:

```
incompatible declaration of built-in function log2f
```

I checked libm.so (where log2f should be) which is on the target device and of course there is no log2f function defined there but replacing the library by hand probably would crash some other stuff + I need to root the phone.

I know this is a linker issue and it should not be that hard to fix but I ran out of ideas.

EDIT:
I'm trying to compile ffmpeg 2.4.3
The script that I'm using to configure:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$NDK" = "" ]; then
    echo NDK variable not set, assuming ${HOME}/android-ndk
    export NDK=${HOME}/android-ndk
fi

echo "Compiling with NDK located at: $NDK"

ROOT_DIR=`cd ..; pwd`
CUR_DIR=`pwd`

echo "Fetching Android system headers"
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/base" ]; then
    git clone --depth=1 --branch cm-11.0 https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base.git "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/base"
fi
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/system/core" ]; then
    git clone --depth=1 --branch cm-11.0 https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_system_core.git "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/system/core"
fi
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/av" ]; then
    git clone --depth=1 --branch cm-11.0 https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/av"
fi
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/hardware/libhardware" ]; then
    git clone --depth=1 --branch cm-11.0 https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_hardware_libhardware.git "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/hardware/libhardware"
fi
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/native" ]; then
    git clone --depth=1 --branch cm-11.0 https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_native.git "$ROOT_DIR/android-source/frameworks/native"
fi

echo "Fetching Android libraries for linking"
# Libraries from any froyo/gingerbread device/emulator should work
# fine, since the symbols used  should be available on most of them.
if [ ! -d "$ROOT_DIR/android-libs" ]; then
    wget http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/65493/cm-10.2.1.3-serranoltexx.zip -P../
    unzip ../cm-10.2.1.3-serranoltexx.zip system/lib/* -d../
    mv ../system/lib "$ROOT_DIR/android-libs"
    rmdir ../system
    rm ../cm-10.2.1.3-serranoltexx.zip
fi

ANDROID_SOURCE="$ROOT_DIR/android-source"
echo "ANDROID_SOURCE: $ANDROID_SOURCE"
ANDROID_LIBS="$ROOT_DIR/android-libs"
OBJS="$ROOT_DIR/objs"
if [ "$DEST" = "" ]; then
    rm -rf $ROOT_DIR/build/stagefright
    mkdir -p $ROOT_DIR/build/stagefright
    DEST=$ROOT_DIR/build/stagefright
fi

#for ABI in "armeabi-v7a" "armeabi" "x86"; do
for ABI in "armeabi-v7a" "armeabi"; do
    if [ "$ABI" = "x86" ]; then
        ARCH="x86"
        TOOLCHAIN=`echo $NDK/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/*-x86*`
    else
        ARCH="arm"
        TOOLCHAIN=`echo $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/*-x86*`
    fi 
    SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-18/arch-$ARCH
    # Expand the prebuilt/* path into the correct one
    export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH

    FLAGS="--target-os=linux --arch=$ARCH"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-symver"
    if [ "$ARCH" = "arm" ]; then
        FLAGS="$FLAGS --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --cpu=armv7-a --enable-libstagefright-h264"
        #FLAGS="$FLAGS --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --cpu=armv7-a"
    else
        FLAGS="$FLAGS --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/i686-linux-android- --disable-asm"
    fi

    EXTRA_CFLAGS="-I$DEST/$ABI/include"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/base/include -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/system/core/include"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/native/include"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/native/include/media/openmax"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/av/include"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/$ABI/include"
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -I$ANDROID_SOURCE/hardware/libhardware/include"
    if [ "$ARCH" = "arm" ]; then
        EXTRA_CFLAGS="$EXTRA_CFLAGS -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -Wl,--no-undefined" #-Werror=implicit-function-declaration"
    fi
    EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L$ANDROID_LIBS -Wl,-rpath-link,$ANDROID_LIBS -L$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/$ABI"
    EXTRA_CXXFLAGS="-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --prefix=$DEST/$ABI"

    mkdir -p $DEST/$ABI
    mkdir -p $OBJS/$ABI

    echo $FLAGS --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" --extra-cxxflags="$EXTRA_CXXFLAGS" > $DEST/$ABI/info.txt
    echo "Configuring ..."
    cd $OBJS/$ABI
    $ROOT_DIR/configure $FLAGS --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" --extra-cxxflags="$EXTRA_CXXFLAGS" | tee $DEST/$ABI/configuration.txt
    [ $PIPESTATUS == 0 ] || exit 1
    echo "Making ..."
    #make clean
    make -j4 || exit 1
    make install || exit 1
    cd $CUR_DIR
done
```

Comment: Which ffmpeg do you build? How did you `./configure` it?

Comment: ffmpeg 2.4.3. I edited the question by adding the code of the script used to configure

Comment: in my `config.log`, I see check that shows that `log2f` is not there. This results in `HAVE_LOG2F` undefined, and **`libavutils/libm.h`** uses `#define log2f(x) ((float)log2(x))`. That's how my build works on Android 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the latest NDK, only set platform to android-19 and not the latest android-21.

You use the libraries from some [cyanogenmod build](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/65493/cm-10.2.1.3-serranoltexx.zip), which are "too good". For example, you get from there a `libm.so` that has `log2()`. Instead, you need the least common denominator of `libm.so` versions on supported devices. You don't need to look for such library; you have the "official" version in NDK.

I understand that to enable hardware codec, you need some "unofficial" libs. But be careful and put the directory with the downloaded libs closer to the end of your lookup list. Or safer still, only copy the few libs (like `libcutils.so`) that your link really needs.

Comment: Thanks Alex, finally it works!
how: I switched to another "set" of libraries http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/42509/cm-10.1.3-i9305.zip which are the ones shipped in a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.0.4). Of course, because in that libm.so there's no log2 and log2f now I don't get the built-in warning neither the link error (expected behaviour!). In any case, I would like to know how it's done when an application is compiled with an NDK which has functions that are not implemented in the system libraries of the device (Android version lower than NDK toolchain).

Comment: ah, I forgot to mention: on Android 5 it's not working (sadly I was expecting this). The error is: failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android16MediaBufferGroup14acquire_bufferEPPNS_11MediaBufferE" referenced by "libavcodec.so"...

Comment: I am afraid I did not explain it clear enough. NDK comes with a set of libraries for each platform that represent the "contract" for that platform. I.e. if you use **libm.so** from android-platform 8, then any device from 2.2 and higher will have **libm.so** that will be backwards compatible. I strongly recommend that you only use the few missing system libraries that your build needs, and not to override the ones shipped with NDK.

Comment: Regarding **MediaBuffer**, this is an example of *non-official libraries* not being backwards compatible. The easiest way around is to create a separate `libavcodec.so` for Lollipop. The tricky way is to build an adaptor library that will be used to tune one library for both.